# Launch Google Maps Native Application Android phonegap

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a kml file that I need to display in the google maps **native** application from a phonegap android app. I can get the kml loaded by a simeple a href to the file and Google Map launches

The problem I have is that when the user hits the back button on the phone it goes back to the start of my application, the login page, not the page they launched the kml file from.

So I can see 2 solutions but need help in implementation

1. Fix the back button problem
2. Try and do something with web intents to load a kml file or display a loadof markers

Any help would be greatly received

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

And uncheck in developer options->Do not keep activities